# can't install any package with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip

I'm using ArtixLinux as OS.

I can't use pip for installing package with pip.

I got this error:

```py
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 341, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 454, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 319, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 176, in _merge_into_criterion
    crit = Criterion.from_requirement(self._p, requirement, parent)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 79, in from_requirement
    matches = provider.find_matches(requirements=[requirement])
TypeError: PipProvider.find_matches() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'identifier' and 'incompatibilities'
```

I tried reinstall python-pip and python-resolvelib to see if the error solved but no!!

but I can use pip inside a venv, no errors for download or installing any package except PyGObject.

I got this error when trying to install PyGObject inside venv:

```py
Collecting PyGObject
  Using cached PyGObject-3.42.1.tar.gz (718 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pycairo>=1.16.0
  Using cached pycairo-1.21.0-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: PyGObject
  Building wheel for PyGObject (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for PyGObject (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [42 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat/generictreemodel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/pygtkcompat
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi
      copying gi/types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi
      copying gi/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi
      copying gi/module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi
      copying gi/importer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi
      copying gi/docstring.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi
      copying gi/_signalhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi
      copying gi/_propertyhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi
      copying gi/_ossighelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi
      copying gi/_option.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi
      copying gi/_gtktemplate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi
      copying gi/_error.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi
      copying gi/_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi
      copying gi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi/repository
      copying gi/repository/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi/repository
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/keysyms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Pango.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Gtk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Gio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GdkPixbuf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Gdk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GObject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GLib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GIMarshallingTests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/gi/overrides
      running build_ext
      Package gobject-introspection-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gobject-introspection-1.0.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      Package 'gobject-introspection-1.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
      Command '('pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 1.56.0')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyGObject
Failed to build PyGObject
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyGObject, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: So when you install `gobject-introspection-1.0` you still get the error that it's not found?

Comment: @RandomDavis in python there is no package named `gobject-introspection-1.0` or `gobject-introspection` but there is `gobject-introspection` in archlinux repositories. I have all of my dependencies installed by pacman but inside a venv it must installed with pip.

Comment: That's not a Python package though, it's a linux package that's missing

Comment: @RandomDavis the pygobject problem solved. the main problem still alive!!

Comment: I don't know anything about Artix, but on most other distributions `Perhaps you should add the directory containing gobject-introspection-1.0.pc` would suggest that you're missing the development package for `gobject-introspection`.

Comment: P.S.: This is not a problem with pip or python, but with you not understanding what pip is trying to do, namely compiling something from you.

Comment: @tink so what should I do?? I didn't understand

Comment: Install `gobject-introspection-dev` if it exists in your distro.

Comment: @tink there is `gobject-introspection-runtime` and `gobject-introspection`. both are installed.

Comment: Do either of them provide the file `gobject-introspection-1.0.pc`?

Comment: @tink yes. file provided by `gobject-introspection`

Answer (score 1):

i am on artix to and have been following this thread bc i had the exact same problems. seems like a package problem

do a -Syu (maybe a reboot.) then redo your original task.
my pip works now.